# Oracle: Replace multiple string occurrences

Tags: regex, string, oracle, replace

Just a quick check, is it possible to replace all the occurrences with a single select statement. If not, we plan to write a function to do this replace.

**Sample string**

```
select '#col1:val1@, #col2:val2@, #col3:val3@, #col4:val4@, #col5:val5@' str from dual
```

**Expected output**

```
str
---
col1 val1, col2 val2, col3 val3, col4 val4, col5 val5
```

**Code so far**

```
with test_table as 
(Select '#col1:val1@, #col2:val2@, #col3:val3@, #col4:val4@, #col5:val5@' str from dual)

   select level "occurrence", REGEXP_substr(str, '#(.*?):', 1, level, 'in', 1) "column", REGEXP_substr(str, ':(.*?)@', 1, level, 'in', 1) "value"
   from test_table
   CONNECT BY REGEXP_COUNT(str, '#.+?:.+?@') >= level
```

**Additional Details**

1. String pattern is fixed and known beforehand.
2. Occurrence of the given pattern is dynamic, may have any number of [column:value] pairs - they are actually [table column:alias] set.
3. I have trimmed the sample string for simplicity, however it contains additional details (table joins, where clause etc.), so we would need to replace all the occurrences. It’s actually a select statement.

Answer (score 3):

**Query**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         '#col1:val1@, #col2:val2@, #col3:val3@, #col4:val4@, #col5:val5@',
         '#(.*?):(.*?)@',
         '\1 \2'
       ) AS str
FROM   DUAL
```

**Output**:

```
STR
-----------------------------------------------------
col1 val1, col2 val2, col3 val3, col4 val4, col5 val5
```

Answer (score 0):

My try:

```
with test_table as 
(Select '#col1:val1@, #col2:val2@, #col3:val3@,     #col4:val4@, #col5:val5@' str 
 from dual)

select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(str, '[#@]', ''), '[ :]+', ' ') rez 
from test_table
;
```

The inner regexp_replace replaces the # and @ with nothing(empty string) and the outer regexp replaces the : and spaces with one space.